# instances of 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null'

Tags: javascript, json

For some reason my if statement here, occasionally throws the below error and I can't figure out why:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null
```

**Here**; I also tried rewriting it in reverse and it still throws on '`.includes`', but then sometimes it works perfectly without error?

```
if (['en','or', 'de', 'ur', 'bn', 'ch'].some(original_language => item.original_language.includes(original_language))) {
    // content happens
}
```

---

**More** relevant **code**:

```
jQuery.ajax({   
                url: "https://www.aworkingapi.com",
                type: "GET",
    },
    success: function(data){                    

              $.each(data.content, function (index, item) {
                    if (['en','or', 'de', 'ur', 'bn', 'ch'].some(original_language => item.original_language.includes(original_language))) {
                    html += "<div class="customContent">";
                    html += "<div class='original_language'><span class='b'>Lan:</span> " + item.original_language + "</div>";

                    // more content
                    },
                    dataType: 'json'    
                  }
                })
```

Comment: Show us what `item` is and where you got it from. It's the one whose `.original_language` is `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.original_language` maybe `null` in some `item` of `data.content`, you can print out `data.content` via `console.log`, you can see `item(s)` without `.original_language`.

I sugest you need check `.original_language` is exist or not ( and it is a array).

```
if (['en','or', 'de', 'ur', 'bn', 'ch'].some(original_language => item.original_language && item.original_language.includes(original_language))) {
    // content happens
}
```